# Deleting Images Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a cross platform mobile app in which i display the images in grid view from SD card.But i want to delete the images once the user clicks each image.
 I have tried using remove() but it didn't works.can anyone tell me what i have to do.

```
function listDir(directoryEntry, domParent){
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); // show loading message  
var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();    
alert(directoryEntry.toURL());
var s=directoryEntry.toURL();
directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){ // success get files and folders
    for(var i=0; i<entries.length; ++i){            
        if( i%2 == 0) domParent.append('<div class="ui-block-a"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="'+s+""+entries[i].name+'" title="'+entries[i].name+'" /></div></div>');
        else domParent.append('<div class="ui-block-b"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="'+s+""+entries[i].name+'" title="'+entries[i].name+'" /></div></div>');                    
        console.log(entries[i].name);
      console.log(entries[i].fullPath);       
    }
    $("#back").click(del);
    function del(){
    for(var i=0;i<entries.length;++i){
    entries[i].delete;
    entries[i].remove(function(file){
        console.log("File removed!");
    },function(){
        console.log("error deleting the file " + error.code);
        });
    }
    alert("Image deleted");
         window.location="camera.html";

    }         
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // hide loading message
}, function(error){ // error get files and folders
    alert(error.code);
});
```

**Displaying images**

```
function showImage(){
    var imgs = $('#gallery img');
    imgs.live('click', function(){       
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('#picture h1').text(title);
        $('#pic').html($(this).clone());        
        $.mobile.changePage($('#picture'));        
    });
}
```

Comment: can you show your html content too ?

Comment: `i want to delete the images` from the `html` or from the `sd card`?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
entries[i].delete;
```

There's no such delete property.
If you want to remove some property from array then use

```
 delete entries[i];
```

But it will not empty the array but will insert undefined in those indexes

If you want to empty an array at once i.e. in one step

```
entries = []
```

or

```
entries.length = 0
```

As far as removing images from DOM is concerned you can use

```
$('#gallery img').remove()
```

Create one fiddle for similar scenario:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bezs5L8u/1/)

Comment: when i give $('#gallery img').remove() it hides the image but when i see the sd card  the images still exists.

Comment: Did you try emptying the array as suggested??

Comment: No i want the selected pic to be deleted instead of deleting the whole .

Comment: You mean when you click on some specific button or whatever then whatever images are selected should be removed from SD card and DOM. Is it??

Comment: I have tried to create similar scenario in Fiddle. You might have to change the array names as per your requirement. Let me know if you have any issues understanding the fiddle. 

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bezs5L8u/1/)

Comment: @AbacusRathu Added the fiddle in Answer.Can you accept it if it's useful??

Comment: how to do that Diljohn

Comment: [See this link] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)